# Imagem deforma-se quando mudo de página

Tags: php, html, css

Olá, eu fiz um primeiro ficheiro index.html em que tem um footer com as algumas informações e pequenas imagens.
De seguida criei outras páginas secundárias com o mesmo footer ( exactamente igual ) só que as imagens, do footer, nas páginas secundárias têm dimensões diferentes das do index...

OBS: As imagens das páginas secundárias têm a mesma dimensão sendo as do index as "correctas".

Já soube que as páginas se forem .html , que aparece bem, e se forem .php que aparece deformado... tentando ainda resolver

Comment: Ok, você parece novo no site, aconselho a REFAZER o tour e aprender a fazer perguntas da forma correta. Assim você não vai obter resposta. A primeira coisa que te aconselho é disponibilizar o código do que você está falando pra gente. Sem um ponto de partida não existe corrida.

Comment: Você fez o mesmo link com o CSS na página secundária?

Comment: Sim, é tudo igual. A única diferença é que um é .html e outro é .php. Já estive a mexer no CSS de modo a por os 2 semelhantes (mas não a 100%)